# find complains if -exec executes tar with --remove-files

Tags: linux, bash, find, tar

**Problem**

I am trying to archive and compress some directories (and their contents) on a GNU/Linux machine and have the original directories (and their contents) removed afterwards.

**Minimum reproducable example**

Here some code to recreate the situation on a GNU/Linux machine:

```sh
cd /tmp
mkdir find_and_tar
cd find_and_tar
mkdir files
mkdir texts
touch files/file1 files/file2 files/file3
touch texts/text1
```

`tree` should now give the following:

```
.
├── files
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   └── file3
└── texts
    └── text1
```

**What I've tried so far**

Now, my command to achieve the stated goal thus far is:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -type d -exec tar --remove-files -cJf {}.tar.xz {} \;
```

It does what it is supposed to do - `tree` now gives:

```
.
├── files.tar.xz
└── texts.tar.xz
```

BUT the command throws the following warnings:

```
find: ‘./texts’: No such file or directory
find: ‘./files’: No such file or directory
```

If I were to remove the `--remove-files` modifier, the warnings disappear but obviously the original dirs stay around.

**Question(s)**

1. Why do these `find` warnings appear?
2. How do I avoid them?

**Version info**

```
$ tar --version
tar (GNU tar) 1.30
$ find --version
find (GNU findutils) 4.6.0.225-235f
```

Comment: Unrelated, but you aren't gzipping the tarballs, so don't use the `.gz` extension.

Comment: @chepner thanks for the hint - corrected it in the question

Comment: unix.stackexchange.com might be a better place to ask this question.

Comment: I can confirm that (using the `-D all` option) that `find` tries to visit each directory after `tar` completes. I do not know why.

Comment: I've been looking at the ``-D all`` output as well. I assume it is related to the recursive nature of ``find`` as the only difference between the "visits" are the ``prev_depth`` attributes.

Comment: yep, confirmed my suspicion: adding ``-maxlevel 1`` to the ``find`` call fixes the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `find` is still processing the files in the tree during the time that the `tar` is running.
When you only need to process directories at the top level, your `-maxdepth 1` will work. Two alternatives:

**Use `find` option `depth` for looking in the subdirs first**
This might be useful when you need to find directories in different levels:

```
find . -mindepth 1 -depth -type d -exec tar --remove-files -cJf {}.tar.xz {} \;
```

**Avoid `find`**

```
for d in */; do
  tar --remove-files -cJf "${d%/}".tar.xz "${d%/}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

**Analysis**

Adding the `-D all` option to the `find` call to get more insight into what's going on, gave this (amongst others):

```
Optimized command line:
 ( -mindepth 1 [est success rate 1] [real success rate 0/0=_] -a [est success rate 0.0922] [real success rate 0/0=_] [need type] -type d [est success rate 0.0922] [real success rate 0/0=_]  ) -a [est success rate 0.0922] [real success rate 0/0=_] -exec tar [est success rate 1] [real success rate 0/0=_]
consider_visiting (early): ‘.’: fts_info=FTS_D , fts_level= 0, prev_depth=-2147483648 fts_path=‘.’, fts_accpath=‘.’
consider_visiting (late): ‘.’: fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 ignore=1 have_stat=1 have_type=1
consider_visiting (early): ‘./texts’: fts_info=FTS_D , fts_level= 1, prev_depth=0 fts_path=‘./texts’, fts_accpath=‘texts’
consider_visiting (late): ‘./texts’: fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 ignore=0 have_stat=1 have_type=1
consider_visiting (early): ‘./texts’: fts_info=FTS_DNR, fts_level= 1, prev_depth=1 fts_path=‘./texts’, fts_accpath=‘texts’
find: ‘./texts’: No such file or directory
consider_visiting (early): ‘./files’: fts_info=FTS_D , fts_level= 1, prev_depth=1 fts_path=‘./files’, fts_accpath=‘files’
consider_visiting (late): ‘./files’: fts_info=FTS_D , isdir=1 ignore=0 have_stat=1 have_type=1
consider_visiting (early): ‘./files’: fts_info=FTS_DNR, fts_level= 1, prev_depth=1 fts_path=‘./files’, fts_accpath=‘files’
find: ‘./files’: No such file or directory
consider_visiting (early): ‘.’: fts_info=FTS_DP, fts_level= 0, prev_depth=1 fts_path=‘.’, fts_accpath=‘.’
consider_visiting (late): ‘.’: fts_info=FTS_DP, isdir=1 ignore=1 have_stat=1 have_type=1
```

Please note that the second visit in e.g. `./texts` is only different to the previous visit in the `prev_depth` value. I figured that `find` tries to recurse the whole directory tree even after `tar` has already removed the top level directory.

One can see the impact of this recursion by slightly adapting the scenario:

- adding a `subfiles` dir to `files`
- and running the `find` call without `--remove-files` and `-maxdepth`

This will lead to the `subfiles` dir being archived separately within the unarchived `files` dir.

**Solution**

Since I know that I want to archive the top level directories, adding the `-maxdepth 1` option to my `find` call solved the problem for me.